# QGIS 3 missing symbols

Tags: qgis

QGIS 3 symbols like bridleway and construction are missing. When I have updated from other versions there has never been a problem. Where are they now?

Answer (score 3):

Bridleway and Construction road are default line symbol styles. The should be in exactly the same place in QGIS 3 as they were in previous versions: in the Layer Style panel and in the Symbology tab of the Layer Properties window. Here you can see them in a screenshot from my computer, where I have QGIS 3.4.5 installed on Windows 10.

[image]

If you recently updated your version of QGIS and the default symbol styles were missing, you probably had something go wrong when you installed QGIS. Reinstalling QGIS might fix the issue, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Instead, you can import a [Symbol Library](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html) from the Style Manager window (see below for an illustration of how to open the Style Manager).

[image]

I exported the Bridleway and Construction road symbols, and pasted them below. Copy the code block into a text file, save it with the file extension .XML, and import it through the Style Manager.

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis_style>
<qgis_style version="1">
  <symbols>
    <symbol type="line" clip_to_extent="1" alpha="1" name="Bridleway" tags="QGIS 2" force_rhr="0">
      <layer locked="0" enabled="1" pass="0" class="SimpleLine">
        <prop k="capstyle" v="round"/>
        <prop k="customdash" v="5;2"/>
        <prop k="customdash_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="customdash_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="draw_inside_polygon" v="0"/>
        <prop k="joinstyle" v="round"/>
        <prop k="line_color" v="122,245,0,255"/>
        <prop k="line_style" v="solid"/>
        <prop k="line_width" v="1.56"/>
        <prop k="line_width_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
        <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
        <prop k="use_custom_dash" v="0"/>
        <prop k="width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <data_defined_properties>
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
            <Option name="properties"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
          </Option>
        </data_defined_properties>
      </layer>
      <layer locked="1" enabled="1" pass="0" class="SimpleLine">
        <prop k="capstyle" v="round"/>
        <prop k="customdash" v="5;2"/>
        <prop k="customdash_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="customdash_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="draw_inside_polygon" v="0"/>
        <prop k="joinstyle" v="round"/>
        <prop k="line_color" v="85,170,0,255"/>
        <prop k="line_style" v="dot"/>
        <prop k="line_width" v="1.36"/>
        <prop k="line_width_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
        <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
        <prop k="use_custom_dash" v="0"/>
        <prop k="width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <data_defined_properties>
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
            <Option name="properties"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
          </Option>
        </data_defined_properties>
      </layer>
    </symbol>
    <symbol type="line" clip_to_extent="1" alpha="1" name="Construction road" tags="QGIS 2" force_rhr="0">
      <layer locked="0" enabled="1" pass="0" class="MarkerLine">
        <prop k="interval" v="2"/>
        <prop k="interval_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="interval_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
        <prop k="offset_along_line" v="0"/>
        <prop k="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_along_line_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="placement" v="interval"/>
        <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
        <prop k="rotate" v="1"/>
        <data_defined_properties>
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
            <Option name="properties"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
          </Option>
        </data_defined_properties>
        <symbol type="marker" clip_to_extent="1" alpha="1" name="@Construction road@0" force_rhr="0">
          <layer locked="0" enabled="1" pass="0" class="SimpleMarker">
            <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
            <prop k="color" v="255,0,0,255"/>
            <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
            <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
            <prop k="name" v="square"/>
            <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
            <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
            <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
            <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
            <prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
            <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
            <prop k="scale_method" v="area"/>
            <prop k="size" v="1.5"/>
            <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
            <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
            <data_defined_properties>
              <Option type="Map">
                <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                <Option name="properties"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
              </Option>
            </data_defined_properties>
          </layer>
        </symbol>
      </layer>
    </symbol>
  </symbols>
  <colorramps/>
</qgis_style>
```

Or, if you still have the previous version of QGIS installed, then you should still have all the old QGIS symbol styles. Find the symbol library, and import it into your new version of QGIS.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Much appreciated.It did not download correctly when I installed originally. All I had was the cat paws !!