# Where can I find common symbology presets for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, style-manager

I am looking for a collection of basic, common styles that I can just apply in QGIS.

In ArcGIS, I am used to having a comprehensive set of common symbology options built-in, e.g. different road types, common map markers. This is especially useful for beginners. I teach GIS and the most rewarding thing is letting students put together an impressive symbology with just a few clicks.

[image: ArcMap having a comprehensive set of basic, common symbology options built-in]

In QGIS, I am missing a proper equivalent set of presets. The offered ones are really limited to suggestions and honestly anything but impressive, e.g. for "common" traffic there is only "railway", "main road" and "road", but one could add "ferry lines", "cycling trails", "hiking trails", "autobahn"... there are many "common" styles and variations.
[image: QGIS has only a very limited selection]

To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, I mean "common base-styles", e.g. different road- and traffic-types, rivers, symbols for hiking maps like the ones used here:
[image: example for common base-styles]

In [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328051/qgis-3-missing-symbols) I am seeing a few more styles. Is it just that I am missing something to find built-in styles? Or are these probably self-made?

With QGIS being OpenSource, I was hoping to easily find good collections - even comprehensive sets of various "symbol styles" (antique, minimalistic, different countries...). I would even pay for this. However my searches so far have brought up a few scattered ressources and the "official" style repository:
https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/.
This is a good start, but a rather random collection and I haven't really found a comprehensive collection of "standardized" bacis.
The closest thing to what I have in mind is this swedish collection from https://style-hub.github.io/:
[image: swedish]

**Is there more?
Where can I find a comprehensive collection of common styles?**

---

I know, I can just create my own set of styles and I know about the built-in SVG markers (which is okay for a start, but could be bigger, too). But I don't do maps that often that I established a large collection of presets. And for me it is also easy enough to recreate any style I need. However I'd gladly offer my students a nice set of symbols out-of-the-box.

I have switched from ESRI ArcGIS to QGIS for most of my tasks some time ago and really became a QGIS fanboy. But - despite being really powerful in its options - the limited presets in combination with the complex, unintuitive symbology panel is really still a consistent disadvantage.

Comment: Have a look at the QGIS Resource Sharing https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/  You wont really find standardized symbol set but a lot of more or less specific symbol set or SVG collection. I guess the Swedish Landmäteriet, OSM Spatialite Googlemaps and OpenStreetMap style would be the closest to your need

Comment: These are colour palettes that I just found out (https://geoobserver.wordpress.com/2023/06/20/dataviz-wissenschaftliche-farbkarten-auch-fur-qgis/?fbclid=IwAR1Sm-uEXDO9H9CutqFiYCEK0fK-CeEwDqZkDyB9HgnGtdrN4I3Pr85_cRQ). You need to download them first but they are colour-blind friendly and they are for _scientific_ use.